# Is there a way to catch the "An unexpected network error occurred" exception specifically, or to manually throw it (for testing)?

Tags: c#, exception, ioexception

**Background:**

I have a CSV file containing a list of filepaths. Each file needs to be copied from the filepath to a new location over the network. My program handles this fine, however there are occasional network blips, which throw an `IOException` with the message "`An unexpected network error occurred.`". When this happens, I want to retry a few times (with a short delay) before giving up (if a retry is successful, the program would continue as normal). At the minute, I am catching `IOException` and using the `Message` value to determine whether to retry or throw, however it doesn't appear to be retrying as expected. I assume this is because the message I'm comparing isn't quite the same, but I can't think of how I can verify as the problem is occasional.

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to replicate this error (without just creating a new `IOException` with the relevant `Message`)?
- Is there a better way of isolating this particular error?

**Sample Code:**

```
private static void CopyFile(FileInfo file, string destinationFilepath)
{
    try
    {
        file.CopyTo(destinationFilepath);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        var saved = false;
        if (e.Message == "An unexpected network error occurred.")
        {
            saved = RetryCopyFile(file, destinationFilepath);
        }

        if (!saved)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

private static bool RetryCopyFile(FileInfo file, string destinationFilepath)
{
    var saved = false;

    var maxRetries = 20
    var retries = 0;
    while (!saved && (retries < maxRetries))
    {
        try
        {
            file.CopyTo(destinationFilepath, true);
            saved = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            retries++;
        }
    }

    return saved;
}
```

Comment: Well when copying a lot of files there can be a bunch of why it doesnt works.. fatal ones, eg disk full, no permission, source file gone missing.. ten theres just the life raining on your parade and try again errors.. You could consider making a stack of your files to copy, with retry counters and  if it fails +1 to counter, place it back in the stack, once retry counter exceeds tollerances... give up on that 1 file.. move on

Comment: Why are you checking the value of the exception message? I would think that regardless of the reason you'd want to retry if there's an `IOException ` thrown.

Comment: Have you tried logging the IOException error messages - put an else statement after "if (e.Message == "An unexpected network error occurred.")" to filter out that message? Do you know it is not retrying as expected or is it just the fact the file is not copied that makes you think that (see @BugFinder's comment).

Comment: @Hintham What made me think to isolate this one was seeing that 'file already exists' is also an `IOException` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0e105zt(v=vs.110).aspx). If this was the error, I wouldn't necessarily want to retry - I may want to handle it differently. This made me wonder about other errors that fall into the `IOException`. I haven't come across others so far, so I thought it best to just isolate these two specifically and log any others.

Comment: @AmyBarrett then my suggestion becomes even more applicable.. you need to do an on error and if error is this, do that else do something else, etc.

Comment: @PaulF I've stripped out quite a bit of code that was irrelevant to the question to keep it simple. If the retries fail, the exception is logged. What made me dubious about whether the retries were happening was that I had `IOException` logs from multiple files within a minute - it should retry 20 times with 10 second delay before giving up and moving onto the next file (i.e. 200 seconds delay between one file and the next), meaning I _shouldn't_ have had multiple logs within one minute.

Comment: @AmyBarret If you want to single out the case where a file might already exist i would do a `File.Exists` check before attempting to copy.

Comment: @Hintham I have already done this (although not shown in the sample code). However, I wondered about other scenarios that would also fall into `IOException` where I would want to handle things differently. For instance, I assume a disk full error would throw an `IOException`. In this case I would want to halt the program altogether and send an alert - there's no point in retrying or attempting the other files, as they would all fail.

Comment: OK, so then use @BugFinder 's suggestion

Comment: @BugFinder Sorry, but I don't see how this is much different to what I'm doing already. If the file doesn't copy (and it's due to a network issue), it retries a few times, using a retry counter, then gives up after a number of retries and moves onto the next file. Please can you explain how your suggestion is different?

Comment: Well, some arent fixable, as I explained.. and would need giving up on, yours also retries the same file again immediately, mine puts it to the bottom of the list .. such as maybe the file you're copying from is in use.. time will fix that

Comment: @BugFinder I see what you mean, and it's a good idea. However, I'd still like to isolate certain errors (e.g. disk full errors) and handle these differently. At the minute, I use `Message`, but if it doesn't behave as expected, I'd like a way to test it by somehow replicating the error. As I mentioned in the question, I suspect the message I'm checking is subtly different to the actual message, and therefore it isn't retrying at all. If this is actually the case, I can't test by creating a new `IOException` with that `Message`, as I'd just be using the wrong `Message` value.

Comment: Yes, but exceptions are different depending on the outcome.. you dont need to rely on exception.message

Comment: @BugFinder Existing files, network issues and disk full all throw `IOException`, however all three should be dealt with in different ways (with the exception of existing files, as that can be checked beforehand), hence why I now need to rely on something different, such as `Message`.